# Git actions - simple if statement condition

Tags: github, github-actions, workflow

Hi Please note that the if condition gets executed in the below case even though the variable "highPriority" is zero.

```
- name: Polaris Result
        id: polaris_result
        run: |
          highPriority=$(cat sample.json | jq '.issueSummary.high')
          echo "$highPriority"
          echo "::set-output name=highPriority::$highPriority"
 
      - name: fail If crosses threshold for high priority issues
        if: ${{ steps.polaris_result.outputs.highPriority }} > 0
        run: exit 1
```

note that echo "$highPriority" outputs "0". However the if condition gets executed in this case which should not be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should surround all the expression with the `{` `}` bracet.
please try:

```
    if: ${{ steps.polaris_result.outputs.highPriority  > 0 }}
```

instead of:

```
    if: ${{ steps.polaris_result.outputs.highPriority }} > 0
```

See [expression](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions) section in the doc for some context